# get content from retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am using [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to deal with web services in android.
My URL response is something like this:

```
{"data": 
    {"cus_detail":
         {
          "id": "1",
          "cus_unique_id": "181612302153223",
          "cus_company_id": "1"
         }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("https://example.com")
            .build();

    Retro service = restAdapter.create(Retro.class);
    service.getFeed(new retrofit.Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Object obj, Response response) {
            Log.v("RETROFIT",obj.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            System.out.println("RETROFIT_ERROR "+retrofitError);
        }
    });
```

Interface:

```
public interface Retro {
   @GET("/user?format=json&method=view_profile&cus_id=1")
   void getFeed(Callback<Object> response);
}
```

I am getting this result:

```
{data={cus_detail={id=1, cus_unique_id=181612302153223, cus_company_id=1}}}
```

How can I retrieve `cus_unique_id` from this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally with Retrofit, you create Java classes that map to your JSON, and use those instead of `Object` in `Callback<Object>`. I find [this tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) helpful for creating the classes. You'd then be able to easily access `cus_unique_id`.

```
service.getFeed(new retrofit.Callback<Data>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Data data, Response response) {
        String cus_unique_id = data.cus_detail.cus_unique_id;
        Log.v("RETROFIT",data.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        System.out.println("RETROFIT_ERROR "+retrofitError);
    }
});
```

Without doing this, I believe the type of `obj` is actually `Map<String, Object>`. So you could try something like the below. Like @GreyBeardedGeek, I don't recommend this approach.

```
service.getFeed(new retrofit.Callback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Object obj, Response response) {
        Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) ((Map<String, Object>) obj).get("data");
        Map<String, Object> cus_detail = (Map<String, Object>) data.get("cus_detail");
        String cus_unique_id = (String) cus_detail.get("cus_unique_id");
        Log.v("RETROFIT",obj.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        System.out.println("RETROFIT_ERROR "+retrofitError);
    }
});
```

Comment: The first half of the answer is the correct one. I wouldn't recommend the second part.

Comment: What will be there in Data class?

Comment: @RonakPatel Much better to let the Json parser parse the all of the Json, instead of having it half-parse it (into  A map of maps), and then mucking about in the implementation details of what the parser produced.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek: In first case, I need to create separate classes for each `json` response. right?

Comment: yes, the usual pattern is to have a package of 'domain' or 'model' objects that represent your data, and which map to the JSON.